# How to create a new row based on custom value ID in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Am having a table with id as primary key not auto increment, I need to push the custom value as an ID. I tried with firstOrNew() and findOrCreate() and create() by pushing the ID as an argument like

```
$var_id = '99';
$var = Table::findOrCreate(['id'=>$var_id]);
return $var;
```

But its creating new row with 0 as ID. Can any one please suggest me how to create ID with 99.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you create your table manually or through a migration? Make sure your id is set to "auto-increment" on your table.  If you create through a migration it would look something like this `$table->increments('id');`

Answer (score 0):

Try laravel query builder its flexible to use.

> DB::table('tablename')->insert(
>          array('id' => '99'));

For more help check this link out 
[Laravel 4.2 query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're code has a small typo, in your case you probably want to use `firstOrCreate` or `findOrNew`.

Either way, by default all model attributes are guarded.
Add `id` to your model fillable array, like so:

```
protected $fillable = ['id']; // perhaps more ?
```

And try again.